# How do I instaniate a gameobject using a transform array randomly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

What I want to do is make a random key spawn point generator using transform arrays to get the key to spawn at a specific spot. Here is the code

```cs
public GameObject theKeyItself;
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
void Start()
{
    //GameObject selectedObject = spawnPoints.GetRandom(); (error)
    ChooseSpawnPoint();
    //chosenSP = spawnPoints(Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length).position); (error)
}
void ChooseSpawnPoint()
{
    //SpawnObjectsHere
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Break your question down into sub questions

- How do I instantiate a game object using a transform?

`Transform t = Instantiate(transformPref, position, rotation, parent);`

- How do I select from an array randomly?

`arr[Random.Range(0, arr.Count)];`

Now put them together

```
Transform transformPref  = transformArray[Random.Range(0, transformArray.Count)];
Transform t = Instantiate(transformPref, position, rotation, parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `theKeyItself` is a prefab you have to use `Instantiate` and

```
public GameObject theKeyItself;
public Transform[] spawnPoints;


void Start()
{
    Transform theKeyItselfCopy = Instantiate(theKeyItself).transform;

    Transform randomSpawnPoint = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];
    ChooseSpawnPoint(theKeyItselfCopy, randomSpawnPoint);

}
void ChooseSpawnPoint(Transform key, Transform spawnPoint)
{
    key.position = spawnPoint.position;
}
```